# Shiai (試合?) vs kyousou (競争?) in martial arts

Tags: word-choice, meaning, usage, word-usage, sports

Within Shodokan Aikido, we practice something we call *Randori* (乱取り) in which two players fight one vs the other. Mostly, it is a tool for learning how to use Aikido versus a strongly resisting opponent. It is a *learning tool* and not used to determine who's best.

*Shiai* (試合?) is what we call the next level: it is a determination of who's best in that bout at this time. But there are no referees, no crowd, no medal, and no glory.

*Kyousou* (競争?) on the other hand is what we call *shiai* when there are referees, crowds, medals, and glory of winning a tournament.

Are we using all those terms correctly or have we made an utter mess of it?

Answer (score 5):

The second one (it is a determination of who's best in that bout at this time. But there are no referees, no crowd, no medal, and no glory.) is called "練習試合{れんしゅうじあい}"

競争{きょうそう}(kyousou) means competition or bout in a very broad sense. There is not necessarily any implication of a sports match with a crowd, referees etc.

> "宇宙{うちゅう}開発{かいはつ}競争{きょうそう}" "the space development race"

"乱取り" is a term meaning specifically the training of "合気道" or "柔道"

So you have three types of activities, "乱取り," "練習試合," and "（公式）試合."

"公式{こうしき}試合{しあい}" or "公式{こうしき}試合{じあい}"